# How to copy a row but change some value in columns sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example i have a table name Info have 3 columns ID,COST,CITY
[image]

```
INSERT INTO Info
  SELECT *
  FROM Info;
  WHERE Cost = 100
```

This will Create exact same copy of 1st row.

I want that new entry need to be ***1,250,pune***

[image]

How can I do when i have 100 columns and need to change only 5 columns thats the real deal?

Comment: The ID can not be equals in the two records

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the new value into the `select`:

```
INSERT INTO Info (Cost, city)
 SELECT 250,city
 FROM Info
 WHERE Cost = 100
```

But the ID can not be copied, because an id should be unique

If your ID isn't an auto_increment you can add the id to the queries:

```
INSERT INTO Info (ID, Cost, city)
 SELECT ID,250,city
 FROM Info
 WHERE Cost = 100
```

Comment: It is giving ID null

Comment: Isn't your `ID` an auto_increment?

Comment: No its just a simple column

Comment: @AnkitVashisht Then see the seconat part of my answer. But in my eyes an id should be unique

Comment: If i have 100 columns and i want to change only cost and city but left ones are same that is there any shortcut to achieve this

Comment: I don't know anything like that. But a table with 100 columns sounds like very bad db design